# SQL Server / select count users per combination of individual items

Tags: sql-server, select

Users owns licenses, and a plan is a combination of licenses.
Sometimes a user owns an individual license, which is not part of a plan.

I want to count the number of users per plan. In the exemple below, it should return :

```
PlanName | Number of Users
P1       | 1
P2       | 2
```

Tables :

```
Users                Licenses                Plans
-----------------    ---------------------   ----------------
Username | UserID    LicenseName|LicenseID   PlanName|PlanID
user1    | 1         L1         | 1          P1      | 1
user2    | 2         L2         | 2          P2      | 2
user3    | 3         L3         | 3
user4    | 4         L4         | 4
                     L5         | 5

UsersAndLicenses        PlansAndLicenses
----------------        ----------------
UserID | LicenseID      PlanID | LicenseID
1      | 1              P1     | 1
1      | 2              P1     | 2
1      | 3              P1     | 3
2      | 4              P2     | 4
2      | 5              P2     | 5
3      | 1
4      | 4
4      | 5
```

I started with a select to get the list of users and plans  (I will apply a count on this select) and I get an issue : user3 who has only L1 (he hasn't a plan) is listed in P1 (L1 is part of P1). My select statement is :

```
SELECT Plans.PlanName, Users.UserName FROM Users
           INNER JOIN (((Licenses INNER JOIN LicensesPlans ON Licenses.LicenseID = LicensesPlans.LicenseID) 
           INNER JOIN Plans ON LicensesPlans.PlanID = Plans.PlanID) 
           INNER JOIN UsersLicenses ON Licenses.LicenseID = UsersLicenses.LicenseID) ON Users.UserID = UsersLicenses.UserID
GROUP BY Plans.PlanName, Users.UserName;
```

What is wrong with my select ?

Comment: Where's the license plan table?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Can you share some sample data as well ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: So just to be clear, a user has a plan exactly when the user has all the licences in the plan? that is, any user who has licences 1 2 3 automatically 'has' plan 1? and the only way for a user to 'have' a plan is by having all the licences the plan includes?

Comment: Yes @AakashM. The user can also have other "individuals" licenses (which are not parts of a plan), but my goal is only to count the number of users per plan, and having a plan is having (at least) the licenses which make the plan

Answer (score 0):

As you are only making counts of how many users for each plan you could probably get away with joining these two tables

```
UsersAndLicenses 
PlansAndLicenses
```

and aggregating the number of users for each plan id.

What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve my issue with just a query.

I created a stored procedure which is called for each user.
This stored procedure use a cursor to scroll through all the plans, retrieve the licenses of each plan and compare them (using an EXCEPT statement) with the licences owned by the user.